using serial RS232 Communication in CANoe CAPL
I am trying to control a power source with CANoe through RS232 Serial Communication, however when I send a command to the power surce using the built in rs232Send function it results in one but the command is not executed on my device
for example I tried sending the command to set the power source in remote control SYSTem:REMote
the function rs232Send returns one but nothing happens on my device. here is the whole code
variables
{
  dword port = 4;
  dword baudrate = 9600;
  dword DataBits = 8;
  dword StopBits = 1;
  dword parity = 0;
  byte Buffer_Send[50], Buffer_Receive[100];
  char Buf_Send[20];
  int Config_Res;
  int Open_Res;
  int Close_Res;
  int Send_Res;
}
on start 
{
  Open_Res = rs232Open(4);
  if (1 == Open_Res)
  {
    write("Device connected succesfully");
  }
  else
  {
    write("Connection failed --> Error");
  }
  Config_Res = rs232Configure(port, baudrate, DataBits, StopBits, parity);
  if (1 == Config_Res)
  {
    write("Device configured correctly");
  }
  else
  {
    write("Device not configured --> Error");
  }
}
on stopMeasurement
{
  rs232Close(4);
  if(1==rs232Close(4))
  { 
    write("Connection closed succesfully");
  }
}
on sysvar sysvar::Agilent::Remote
{ 
  char text[50] = "SYSTem:REMote?\n";
  int i;
  int length;
  length = strlen(text) + 1;
  if (@this == 1)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      Buffer_Send[i] = text[i];
    }
    Send_Res = rs232Send(port, Buffer_Send, length);
  }
  if (Send_Res == 1)
  {
    write("Send succesful");
  }
  else {write("Send failed --> Error");}
  
}


"but the command is not executed" - If there's nothing to indicate that the message is even received, then anything or everything could be broken. Common possible reasons include (a) serial line settings (e.g. baudrate) do not match , (b) improper electrical connection(s) (e.g. missing ground, or TxD connected to TxD instead of RxD), (c) command not formatted correctly, (d) using incorrect port. Find ways to check/verify and eliminate each possibility.

A return value of 1 from RS232Send only means that sending was started successfully. You should implement the callback handlers RS232OnSend and RS232OnError in order to get more information about what is going on.

implement them to do what exactly?

@ZaidMansour  to get more information about what is going on. Take a look at CANoe's documentation for these callbacks. You can get information about why sending has failed from the arguments of the callbacks
